# Filling numbers in image mask with solid white

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I've got an an image with text on a white background and another I want to overlay this text onto.

I've worked out the absdiff between the two images and now have a mask to use to blend the two.

```
img1 * mask + img2 * (1-mask)
```

The issue I have is the outline of my text is BLACK but the center of the text white. But, also the background of SOME of the image is white.

So the mask I've generated is like this currently.

[image]

This is my goal.

[image]

Does anyone have any suggests to fill the numbers with solid white?

I've tried to make the colour of the text a light grey and use np.where but I can't seem to get it to play ball.

EDIT - The images I have are:

The blank axes from matplotlib (if needed)

[image]

The updated BARS converted to images. (Background image) - please ignore the images they are just for testing !! HA

[image]

The Text frame I need to overlay on the BARS image. (image to overlay above)

[image]

Comment: Can you show the original image?

Comment: @amzon-ex done! Thanks

Comment: Check out cv2.floodFill,maybe it can help. Documentation here : https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=floodfill

Comment: Thanks but its trickier than that I think because of the extra information contained in the images. I ended up just re-writing the text over the top of the 1st and 2nd image above.

Comment: This might be overkill, but you can use findContours and then drawContours with a negative value for the thickness. This might even be able to replace how you are creating the mask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do that for the image you presented using Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to gray
- Threshold
- Find the outer contours and draw white filled contours on a black background
- Invert the threshold
- Floodfill with black, then white, then black again
- Find the outer contours and draw black filled contours on the previous white filled contour image
- Save results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('1970.png')

# convert gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold saturation image
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# get outer contours and draw filled ones as white on black background
cntrs = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cntrs = cntrs[0] if len(cntrs) == 2 else cntrs[1]
result1 = np.zeros_like(img)
for c in cntrs:
    cv2.drawContours(result1, [c], 0, (255,255,255), -1)

# invert thresh
thresh2 = 255 - thresh
hh, ww = thresh2.shape

# floodfill thresh2 with black then white then black again
mask = np.zeros([hh + 2, ww + 2], np.uint8)
thresh2 = cv2.floodFill(thresh2, mask, (0,0), 0, 0, 0, flags=8)[1]
mask = np.zeros([hh + 2, ww + 2], np.uint8)
thresh2 = cv2.floodFill(thresh2, mask, (0,0), 255, 0, 0, flags=8)[1]
mask = np.zeros([hh + 2, ww + 2], np.uint8)
thresh2 = cv2.floodFill(thresh2, mask, (0,0), 0, 0, 0, flags=8)[1]

# get outer contours of these holes and draw filled ones as black
cntrs2 = cv2.findContours(thresh2, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cntrs2 = cntrs2[0] if len(cntrs2) == 2 else cntrs2[1]
result2 = result1.copy()
for c in cntrs2:
    cv2.drawContours(result2, [c], 0, (0,0,0), -1)

# antialias if desired as follows:

# blur threshold image
result3 = result2.copy()
result3 = cv2.GaussianBlur(result3, (0,0), sigmaX=9, sigmaY=9, borderType = cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)

# normalize so min=0 and max=255
result3 = cv2.normalize(result3, None, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)

# stretch so that 255 -> 255 and 127.5 -> 0
result3 = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(result3, in_range=(127.5,255), out_range=(0,255))  

# save output image
cv2.imwrite('1970_thresh1.png', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('1970_thresh2.png', thresh2)
cv2.imwrite('1970_result1.png', result1)
cv2.imwrite('1970_result2.png', result2)
cv2.imwrite('1970_result3.png', result3)

# display IN and OUT images
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('thresh2', thresh2)
cv2.imshow('result1', result1)
cv2.imshow('result2', result2)
cv2.imshow('result3', result3)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Threshold:

[image]

White filled contours:

[image]

Inverted threshold after flood filling (the inner holes):

[image]

Binary result:

[image]

Antialiased result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, very helpful. The only issue with this is the outer edge is now SOLID white where as before the outside was faded. This means that it doesn't blend very well. But thank you for the time you spent answering it. I ended up just re-writing the text with PIL anyway.

Comment: You can antialias the outside edges using a gaussian blur and some one-sided thresholding. I have edited my answer to show how.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to preserve the outer pixels that are not 0 or 255, then here is another approach in Python/OpenCV

Input:

[image]

- Read the input
- Convert to gray
- Threshold
- Invert the threshold
- Floodfill with black
- Get the external contours and draw them as white filled contours on black background
- Go back to the inverted threshold and flood fill it with black, then white, then black to get the "holes"
- Get the external contours from that and draw as black on the previous white filled contours
- Add this result to the input image
- Save results

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('1970.png')

# convert gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold saturation image
thresh1 = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# invert thresh
thresh1 = 255 - thresh1
hh, ww = thresh1.shape

# floodfill thresh1 with black
mask = np.zeros([hh + 2, ww + 2], np.uint8)
thresh1 = cv2.floodFill(thresh1, mask, (0,0), 0, 0, 0, flags=8)[1]

# get outer contours and draw filled ones as white on black background
cntrs = cv2.findContours(thresh1, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cntrs = cntrs[0] if len(cntrs) == 2 else cntrs[1]
result1 = np.zeros_like(img)
for c in cntrs:
    cv2.drawContours(result1, [c], 0, (255,255,255), -1)

# floodfill thresh1 with black then white then black again
thresh2 = thresh1.copy()
mask = np.zeros([hh + 2, ww + 2], np.uint8)
thresh2 = cv2.floodFill(thresh2, mask, (0,0), 0, 0, 0, flags=8)[1]
mask = np.zeros([hh + 2, ww + 2], np.uint8)
thresh2 = cv2.floodFill(thresh2, mask, (0,0), 255, 0, 0, flags=8)[1]
mask = np.zeros([hh + 2, ww + 2], np.uint8)
thresh2 = cv2.floodFill(thresh2, mask, (0,0), 0, 0, 0, flags=8)[1]

# get outer contours of these holes and draw filled ones as black on copy of result1 and input
cntrs2 = cv2.findContours(thresh2, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cntrs2 = cntrs2[0] if len(cntrs2) == 2 else cntrs2[1]
result2 = result1.copy()
for c in cntrs2:
    cv2.drawContours(result2, [c], 0, (0,0,0), -1)

# add result2 to input
result3 = cv2.add(result2,img)

# save output image
cv2.imwrite('1970_thresh1b.png', thresh1)
cv2.imwrite('1970_thresh2b.png', thresh2)
cv2.imwrite('1970_result1b.png', result1)
cv2.imwrite('1970_result2b.png', result2)
cv2.imwrite('1970_result3b.png', result3)

# display IN and OUT images
cv2.imshow('thresh1', thresh1)
cv2.imshow('thresh2', thresh2)
cv2.imshow('result1', result1)
cv2.imshow('result2', result2)
cv2.imshow('result3', result3)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

First threshold image after flood filling:

[image]

Filled contours from first threshold image:

[image]

Second threshold image after flood filling ("holes"):

[image]

Hole contours drawn in black on previous contour image:

[image]

Final result adding last result to input:

[image]